# Moving data from one database to another database with auto incriment keys

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have `table1`, `table2` and `table3`, all of them have a primary `serial` key `id` (or think of any auto increment type). `table3` has two foreign keys(`table1 id` and `table2 id`).

The questions is, I have 2 databases(`db_a` and `db_b`) that have the same schema (tables 1,2,3 with same relations). Now how can I insert data from `db_b` into `db_a` in a way that I can keep track of the correct relations between `table3` and the `table1` and `table2`.

**EDIT**

This is not a one time thing, it will reoccur aperiodically.

New data is inserted into `db_a` on daily basis, however data inserts on `db_b` can happen with different regularity. The issue is how to keep track of the auto generated keys for `table1` and `table2` when inserting `table3` data into `db_a`

[image: db schema]

Comment: Which Postgres version ? Before inserting, make sure there are no duplicated data between `db_a` and  `db_b` related to 3 tables.  You might use `pg_dump` to export data from `db_b`, then import to `db_a`, then set 3 sequences of those tables.

Comment: @LuanHuynh thanks for the suggestion. I am using Postgres 9.5, however I am more interest in the design or strategy to perform this rather than how to specifically do it in postgres(I might have to use another DBMS). Also, there are no duplicates in the sense that all the new data (`db_b`) is for a different company, and so are identified with auto incriment keys. Please let me know if you think this is not good practice

Comment: I am not sure that you need to move data once or periodically (every second or every committed transaction). In case of you consider PG as a storage, you could build an `small application` to migrate data from `db_a` to `db_b` periodically.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide required info and define how to merge your data exactly.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I just did

Comment: If you can redesign with UUIDs instead of serial for the primary keys, just do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this... steps

These are the tables for `database1`

```
    create table if not exists table1 (
      id int(11) auto_increment,
      data1 varchar(50),
      primary key(id)
    );
    create table if not exists table2 (
      id int(11) auto_increment,
      data2 varchar(50),
      primary key(id)
    );
    create table if not exists table3 (
      id int(11) auto_increment,
      t1_id int(11),
      t2_id int(11),
      data3 varchar(50),
      primary key(id)
    );
```

There are the tables for  `database2`

```
    create table if not exists 2table1 (
      id int(11) auto_increment,
      data1 varchar(50),
      primary key(id)
    );
    create table if not exists 2table2 (
      id int(11) auto_increment,
      data2 varchar(50),
      primary key(id)
    );
    create table if not exists 2table3 (
      id int(11) auto_increment,
      t1_id int(11),
      t2_id int(11),
      data3 varchar(50),
      primary key(id)
    );
```

Here we have temp data for `database1`

```
    insert into database1.table1 (data1)
        values('table_1_data_1'),
        ('table_1_data_2'),
        ('table_1_data_3');

    insert into database1.table2 (data2)
        values('table_2_data_1'),
        ('table_2_data_2'),
        ('table_2_data_3');

    insert into database1.table3 (data3,t1_id,t2_id)
        values('table_3_data_1',1,1),
        ('table_3_data_2',1,2),
        ('table_3_data_3',2,1),
        ('table_3_data_4',2,2),
        ('table_3_data_5',2,3);
```

temp data for `database2`

```
    insert into database2.2table1 (data1)
        values('2table_1_data_1'),
        ('2table_1_data_2'),
        ('2table_1_data_3');

    insert into database2.2table2 (data2)
        values('2table_2_data_1'),
        ('2table_2_data_2'),
        ('2table_2_data_3');
```

**Now come to the point**

Here we are copying data
from `database1`s `table1` to `database2`s `2table1`

and

from `database1`s `table2` to `database2`s `2table2`

```
    insert into database2.2table1 (data1)
        select data1 from database1.table1;
    insert into database2.2table2 (data2)
        select data2 from database1.table2;
```

Now we are going to insert data into `database2`s `2table3`

```
    insert into database2.2table3 (t1_id,t2_id,data3) select
      (select 2t1.id from database2.2table1 2t1 where 2t1.data1 =t1.data1 ),
      (select 2t2.id from database2.2table2 2t2 where 2t2.data2 =t2.data2 ),
      t3.data3
    from database1.table3 t3
    left join database1.table1 as t1 on t1.id = t3.t1_id
    left join database1.table2 as t2 on t2.id = t3.t2_id;
```

I hope it helps...